# Maxmind GeoLite2-City is_anonymous_proxy and is_satellite_provider always 0

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolitecity

I've downloaded the Maxmind GeoLite2-City.csv file from https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/

I see that the is_anonymous_proxy and is_satellite_provider columns are always 0.

I am trying to figure out why these columns are always 0, and if i send out an IP addr for anonymous proxy, will i get a 0 or a different value.

Is there a API (Java or other languages) to call GeoLite2-City and see if it gives out reliable results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is_anonymous_proxy and is_satellite_provider columns are not always 0. Try the following command to find examples:

```
grep ",1," GeoLite2-City-Blocks-IPv4.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. How reliable are these fields. I randomly picked up a few IPs that were listed as anonymous proxies, and ran against http://www.ip2location.com/demo/ which listed it as Not anonymous.            So, i am now confused as to which one to rely on, and wondering if there is an independent way to find out if an ip is anonymous.